# Semi-dynamic queries and database security

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I know that plain Progress 4GL code with static buffers, find, for each etc. is subject to database security at compile-time (or additionally at run-time with the "Use Runtime Permissions Checking" option).

Dynamic queries are subject to database security at run-time only.

Does anyone know how code like in the following example would behave?

```
define query q for OrderLine.

DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

hQuery = QUERY q:HANDLE.

hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH OrderLine NO-LOCK WHERE OrderLine.Itemnum = 100":U).
hQuery:QUERY-OPEN().

get first q.
do while available OrderLine:

  display OrderLine.Qty.

  get next q.

end.

close query q.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUERY-PREPARE() and QUERY-OPEN() are executed at run-time, the compiler cannot evaluate what the arguments are at compile time so run time is when security will be applied.

(Even though you used a static string for the arguments the compiler isn’t smart enough to do anything with it.)

Comment: I didn't expect the compiler to evaluate the query-prepare string at compile time.

What I'm interested in is if defining the query q for a fixed table and accessing the query through get first/next q and the name of the fixed table would do anything.

Obviously the code wouldn't work if the query-prepare string doesn't match the definition of the query. Just tried what will happen in that case, the query-prepare will throw the error "<table> must be an unabbreviated name of a buffer known in query q. (7327)".

Comment: Security won’t be applied until you try to execute the query.  “FOR orderLine” doesn’t impact that. So it is still run-time.